# What is the support of the Whittaker function of a new vector on GL(2)?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, automorphic-forms, reference-request

Let $W$ be the normalized Whittaker function associated to a new vector in an irreducible generic representation $\pi$ of $G=GL_2(k)$, where $k$ is a $p$-adic field. Let $c$ be the conductor of $\pi$, meaning that $c$ is the smallest integer with $W(gk)=W(g)$ for all $k\in K_1(c)$ where $K_1(c)$ is the subgroup of $K=GL_2({\mathfrak o})$ with bottom row congruent to $(0,1)$ modulo $\mathfrak p^c$ (with the convention that $K_1(0)=K$).

> > What is the support of $W$ restricted to $K$?

Clearly, the support contains $K_0(c)$, the subgroup of upper triangular matrices modulo $\mathfrak p^c$, since $W$ won't vanish on the center of $G$. I imagine it will depend on further information about $\pi$ beyond the conductor, but I'm having trouble finding (or proving) much of anything definitive.

Comment: Why is W non-zero on the centre? All you know that W is non-zero on some coset $U g K_1(c)Z$. Paskunas-Stevens compute some Whittaker
functions for supercuspidals, see http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0603051, 
but the fucntions there will not be new vectors in general, i think.   

Comment: Hi labirintas, thanks for the paper. A general (possibly nontrivial) fact, at least for GL(n), is that $W(1)\ne 0$ (this may require "newform-ness"). Since $W(z)=\omega(z)W(1)$, where $\omega$ is the central character of $\pi$, $W$ is nonzero on the center. More specifically, the "new vector" criterium can also be written as $W(gk)=\omega(d)W(g)$ for $k\in K_0(c)$, $k=\bigg(\matrix{a&b\cr c&d}\bigg)$.

Comment: Dear BR, As you surmise, the answer depends on $\pi$.  Firsly, I think it is more convenient to work in the Kirillov model than in the Whittaker model, but the two are equivalent: working in the Kirillov model means restricting to the torus $(k^{\times} \, 0 ; 0 \, 1)$.  Now if $\pi$ is prinicpal series or special, the new vector has support over  all of $\mathcal O_k \setminus \{0\}$, while if it is cuspidal than the support is just the char. function of $\mathcal O_K^{\times}$.   In the unramified principal series case, this will be discussed in the paper(s?) of Casselman and Shalika ...

Comment: ... They give an explicit formula for the Whittaker function in the unramified principal series case (and for any group $G$, or at least for $GL_n$) called the Casselman--Shalika formula.    I'm not sure of the a reference in the other cases, but the (possibly ramified) principal series case and the special case you can compute yourself just from the basic description in terms of parabolic induction: choose a non-zero additive character $\psi$ and just compute $\pi_{N = \psi}$ directly --- you will see that the map to the Kirillov (or Whittaker) model is given by a kind of Fourier transform.  

Comment: It might be that the general case (i.e. the supercuspidal case as well) is handled in another Casselman paper ("On a theorem of Atkin and Lehner", or something like that) where he discusses the theory of newforms for $GL_2$ from a representation-theoretic viewpoint.   My memory is that I worked it out from that paper, combined with my own fumblings. E.g. you can describe the $U_p$-operator --- using classical Atkin-Lehner notation --- in representation theoretic terms, then consider how it acts in terms of the Kirillov model (easy, because the action of the Borel on the Kirillov model is ...

Comment: ... given by explicit formulas, and the $U_p$-operator only involves matrices from the Borel), and then use the fact that the space of compactly supported vectors on $k^{\times}$ killed by $U_p$ and fixed by $(\mathcal O_k^{\times} \, \mathcal O_k ; 0 \, 1)$ is one-dimensional --- so this vector must be the newform!  (Here I am also using that in the cuspidal case, the image of the Kirillov model is precisely the compactly supported vectors on $k^{\times}$.)  I hope this is of some help, if you want to try to compute it yourself.  (And if you haven't read them, the few pages in ...

Comment: ... Jacquet--Langlands on the formal properties of the Kirillov model, which give e.g. the compact support statement made above, are very helpful.)  Regards, Matthew

Comment: Hi Matthew, thanks for the series of comments. (By the way, the support of the new vector in the Kirillov model for ramified principal series (in both characters, not just one) or ramified special representations is ${\mathfrak o}^\times$, see the paper Paul links to in his answer, and, in fact, the general formula for the Kirillov model of the new vector can be "reverse engineered" from the fact that the Mellin transform is precisely the $L$-function.) I might be able to figure out the answer using the formal series description in JL.

Comment: Dear BR, You are right in the ramified cases; I got myself confused thinking about a slightly different kind of vector (the canonical lift of an eigenvector in the Jacquet module, which coincides with the new vector in the unram. case but not always in the ram. PS case).  Anyway, I'm glad that you've sorted things out!  Cheers,

Answer (score 3):

You should find all ingredients needed for your calculation in the following very useful notes by Ralf Schmidt:

Some remarks on local newforms for GL(2).
J. Ramanujan Math. Soc. 17 (2002), 115-147

It is available on [Ralf Schmidt's webpage](http://www.math.ou.edu/~rschmidt/).

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks for the answer. I do agree that those notes are very useful. In fact, I was looking at it when I thought of the question! :) Perhaps I'm just being dense, but I was unable to see how to use it to get the result I'm interested in. 